# AngularJS : How do I switch views from a controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to use the *ng-click* feature of AngularJS to switch views. How would I go about doing this with the code below?

index.html

```
 <div ng-controller="Cntrl">
        <div ng-click="someFunction()">
            click me
        <div>
    <div>
```

controller.js

```
  function Cntrl ($scope) {
        $scope.someFunction = function(){
            //code to change view?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 315, accepted):

In order to switch between different views, you could directly change the window.location (using the $location service!) in
index.html file

```
<div ng-controller="Cntrl">
        <div ng-click="changeView('edit')">
            edit
        </div>
        <div ng-click="changeView('preview')">
            preview
        </div>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
function Cntrl ($scope,$location) {
        $scope.changeView = function(view){
            $location.path(view); // path not hash
        }
    }
```

and configure the router to switch to different partials based on the location ( as shown here https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/app.js ). This would have the benefit of history as well as using ng-view.

Alternatively, you use ng-include with different partials and then use a ng-switch as shown in here ( https://github.com/ganarajpr/Angular-UI-Components/blob/master/index.html )

Comment: I'm getting an error that says hash is not function of $location.

Comment: I don't see hash as being part of the $location object, but there is a $$hash variable so is that it and if so it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I found out how to do it. $location.path(view);  (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location)

Comment: @The_Brink Thank you for the edit. I dont know why it was rejected. I made changes to reflect what I was attempting to say.

Comment: Edited the response. It should be .path not .hash see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location and http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: The best thing to do actually is just make a normal link. `<a href="/edit">Edit</a>`

Angular will take make sure that the click does not create a page reload. This behavior can be modified so that it triggers a reload if that is desired.

Comment: There's also `$location.url('/path?query')`, which you can use if you need to include a query string. `$location.path()` seems to strip query strings.

Answer (score 38):

The provided answer is absolutely correct, but I wanted to expand for any future visitors who may want to do it a bit more dynamically -

In the view -

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <div ng-click="changeView(person)">
        Go to edit
    <div>
<div>
```

In the controller -

```
$scope.changeView = function(person){
    var earl = '/editperson/' + person.id;
    $location.path(earl);
}
```

Same basic concept as the accepted answer, just adding some dynamic content to it to improve a bit.  If the accepted answer wants to add this I will delete my answer.

Comment: a total nitpick, but FYI, a `url` is actually the __full__ web address, including the protocol (http://) and everything. As implied by `$location.path()` your variable is better described as a `path`.

Comment: But it requires a $rootScope.$digest(); or $scope.$apply(); in order to make it move without a delay.

Answer (score 23):

I've got an example working.

Here's how my doc looks:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/ctrls.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div id="contnr">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what my partial looks like:

```
<div id="welcome" ng-controller="Index">
    <b>Welcome! Please Login!</b>
    <form ng-submit="auth()">
        <input class="input login username" type="text" placeholder="username" /><br>
        <input class="input login password" type="password" placeholder="password" /><br>
        <input class="input login submit" type="submit" placeholder="login!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's what my Ctrl looks like:

```
app.controller('Index', function($scope, $routeParams, $location){
    $scope.auth = function(){
        $location.url('/map');
    };
});
```

app is my module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']).config(function($routeProvider)...
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 12):

The method used for all previous answers to this question suggest changing the url which is not necessary, and I think readers should be aware of an alternative solution.  I use ui-router and $stateProvider to associate a state value with a templateUrl which points to the html file for your view.  Then it is just a matter of injecting the $state into your controller and calling $state.go('state-value') to update your view.

[What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways for this:

If you are using ui-router or `$stateProvider`, do it as:

```
$state.go('stateName'); //remember to add $state service in the controller
```

if you are using angular-router or `$routeProvider`, do it as:

```
$location.path('routeName'); //similarily include $location service in your controller
```

Comment: On thing that tripped me up was using the route name instead of the state name... i.e. it should be "main" instead of "/main"

Answer (score 3):

Without doing a full revamp of the default routing (#/ViewName) environment, I was able to do a slight modification of Cody's tip and got it working great.

the controller

```
.controller('GeneralCtrl', ['$route', '$routeParams', '$location',
        function($route, $routeParams, $location) {
            ...
            this.goToView = function(viewName){
                $location.url('/' + viewName);
            }
        }]
    );
```

the view

```
...
<li ng-click="general.goToView('Home')">HOME</li>
...
```

What brought me to this solution was when I was attempting to integrate a Kendo Mobile UI widget into an angular environment I was losing the context of my controller and the behavior of the regular anchor tag was also being hijacked. I re-established my context from within the Kendo widget and needed to use a method to navigate...this worked.

Thanks for the previous posts!

Answer (score 2):

```
Firstly you have to create state in app.js as below

.state('login', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })

and use below code in controller

 $location.path('login');
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

This little function has served me well:

```
    //goto view:
    //useage -  $scope.gotoView("your/path/here", boolean_open_in_new_window)
    $scope.gotoView = function (st_view, is_newWindow)
    {

        console.log('going to view: ' + '#/' + st_view, $window.location);
        if (is_newWindow)
        {
            $window.open($window.location.origin + $window.location.pathname + '' + '#/' + st_view, '_blank');
        }
        else
        {
            $window.location.hash = '#/' + st_view;
        }


    };
```

You dont need the full path, just the view you are switching to