# using angularjs loading a html snippet on keyboard enter

Tags: angularjs

I am creating my first angularjs app. I have a search input that I want to load a page and display the contents.

```
<input ng-enter="doSomething()" type="text" ng-model="drugSearch"
       datasets="drugSearchDataset" class="sfTypeahead form-control"
       placeholder="Search by generic or brand names">
```

i have also created a directive for capturing the enter key

```
drugformApp.directive('ngEnter', function () {
   return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        if(event.which === 13) {
            scope.$apply(function (){
                scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                scope.searchdrug( $(event.target).val() );
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
   };
});
```

In my controller i have

```
 $scope.searchdrug = function($searchString) {
        var url = URLsArray['typeAheadSrcURL'][URLmode]  + "/%QUERY.json"
        url = url.replace('{filter}',$('#src-button').val());
        url = url.replace('%QUERY.json',$searchString+".json");
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            if ( data.drugmaster.length == 0 ){
                alert("No records found");
                return;
            }
            console.log(data.drugmaster);
        });
    };
```

my $http.get(url) returns some json data.
So I am not sure the correct way to now load a html snippet and populate it.

For other stuff i am doing, my router does something similar. Am i suppose to somehow call the router? this is where i am confused on how best to continue.

Thanks for any help

```
drugformApp.config(function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider ) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/snippets/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
     })
     .when('/search/:drug_Id', {
        templateUrl: '/snippets/drugview.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl'
     })
 });
```

Comment: What html snippet? Where?

Comment: Thats the question. The html snippet is /snippets/searchresults.html. But i am not sure how $scope.searchdrug should load that /snippets/searchresults.html after $http.get or is there a way to call the router ???

Answer (score 0):

This has the answer i needed
[Angular JS::How/when to use ng-click to call a route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201753/angular-jshow-when-to-use-ng-click-to-call-a-route)

a couple of key notes helped

```
app.controller('SlideController', ['$scope', '$location',function($scope, $location){ 
   $scope.goNext = function (hash) { 
   $location.path(hash);
 }

 ;]);
```