# html - href in accordion header not working

Tags: html, angularjs, anchor, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an accordion with links in the header. It is in such a way that the accordion can be opened when clicked anywhere on the header. Because of this when clicked on the link, instead of going to that link (`href`) the accordion is opened.

**Desired behaviour**:

I want the accodion to be opened when clicked anywhere in the header except the link. (i.e when clicked on the link, the user must be redirected and accordion must not be opened)

```
<div>
    <accordion close-others="false">
        <accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="ele in arr">
            <accordion-heading>
                <div>
                    <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
                       ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
                    <div style="width: 50%; float: left; padding-left: 6cm;">{{ele.a}}
                        <span >
                            <a href="https://www.fb.com">link</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <span>{{ele.b}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </accordion-heading>
       </accordion-group>
     </accordion>
  </div>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9dqmE3Ql1BeZOR4sGlKt?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `$event.stopPropagation();` in your ng-click -> `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); fn1();"`

Comment: Sorry about that. fn1() is not used

Comment: I was about to post the same response and fork your plunker. Use $event.stopPropagation();

Comment: you still need to call `$event.stopPropagation()` to prevent any parent click handlers from being notified of the event

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to call [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) inside `ng-click` handler of anchor:

```
<a href="https://www.fb.com" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">link</a>
```

Here's an updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i22oNvD1VndqsAJ9lyWN?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

use

```
ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"//this will not apply accordion click event on this link tag
```

instead of
    ng-click="fn1()"

## This Might not work on plunk try it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When using `accordion-heading`, everything in it will be turned into an `<a>` tag.

Your code will be rendered in brower

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle ng-binding" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" accordion-transclude="heading">
                <div class="ng-scope">
                    <i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
                    <div style="width: 50%; float: left; padding-left: 6cm;" class="ng-binding">1
                        <span>
                            <a href="https://www.fb.com">link</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <span class="ng-binding">2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
    </h4>
```

This is solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/14202514/3901308