# multiple anchor tags click event using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple anchors tags in my document, I want to put only one function for every anchor tag click, For example in jQuery

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(){

    window.location.href='/Home.html'
});
```

How I need to write in angularJs. can you please help me?

Comment: How are you creating those anchor tags?, if you are using ng-repeat directive, then you can set the href property through data binding using the ng-href directive and angular routing will take care of the rest when the anchor tag is clicked, otherwise you can use the ng-click directive to bind to a function on the controller's scope.

Comment: Each anchor tag can be written as `<a href ng-click="goHome()" ...` with a function `$scope.goHome = function() { ... }` in your controller

Comment: check this may be it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18994990/2815635

Comment: If you are using ng-repeat to render the anchor tags and if the url is static you can set it on href property otherwise you can use the ng-href directive to create a dynamic url for the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a directive and add it to anchor tag

```
app.directive('myevent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function($event) {
                $window..location.href = '/Home.html' //your link here
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In your view you can this with anchor tag or normal div like

> `<div myevent class="click">click me</div>`

OR

> `<a myevent href="#">click me</a>`

It just a work around but I prefer you use JQuery that would be much more appropriate for this. Hope this helps. Thank you.

---

There are many other ways like using ng-click with a div tag to do the same.

> `<div ng-click="myEvent()"></div>`

In controller you can use

```
$scope.myEvent() {
 $window..location.href = '/Home.html' //your link here
}
```

Comment: Your directive needs to be restricted to A, not C. And you should be using $window rather than window directly

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you for mentioning. I will update.