# How to make href in button inside collapse

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have a collapsed model which show more information about client, and insid it, I have a button, when I click, I don't get the informations of the specific client, I get data of all clients

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="x in names">
    <a class="item  item-icon-left " >
                <i class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown-circle" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"></i>
                {{x.Marque}}   
              </a>
              <div ng-show="collapsed">
                    <table>
                          <thead >
                             <td>   
                                 <label> Code:  </label> {{x.CodeClient}}    <br/> 
                                 <label> Nom:   </label> {{x.NomClient}}     <br/> 
                                <a class="button button-info" ui-sref="modifClient({CodeClient: x})" >
                                Enregistrer
                                </a> 
        ...
```

app.js

```
     $stateProvider.state('modifClient', {
                    url: '/modifClient',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/modifClient.html',
                    params: {CodeClient: null},
                    controller: 'ConsultClientCtrl' 
                });
app.controller("ConsultClientCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.loadClient = function(){ 
           $http.get("http://localhost/deb/debut.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.names = data; 
           });  
   }
```

});

modifClient.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="ConsultClientCtrl" ng-repeat="x in names | filter: {CodeClient: thisX}" >

  <ion-list ng-repeat="x in names | filter: {CodeClient: thisX}: true">

      <div class="item item-divider center-text" ng-model="CodeClient"> {{x.CodeClient}} </div>
......
```

Comment: Can you please share your controller code?Are you using Angular router?

Comment: $stateProvider.state('modifClient', {
            url: '/modifClient',
            templateUrl: 'templates/modifClient.html',
            controller: 'ConsultClientCtrl' 
        });

Comment: Just post it as an Edit to your question.

Comment: the button works when I put it in other view, but it doesn't work when i put it in this collapse

Comment: It s done, the function from where I get ng-repeat values works fine, because I use it in other view. Thank you

Comment: Then you should use `ui-sref` instead of `href`.

Comment: I tried it, and still not working

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an `<a>` inside another `<a>`.

Comment: I edited it, Thank you, but I still have the same problem

Comment: It's done! I will add the view expected when clicking on button

Comment: I meant `ConsultClientCtrl`.

Comment: I edited it, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the framework's `href`: [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) or `ng-click`

```
<a class="button button-info" ng-href="/modifClient"> ...
```

LE: I've created a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWeVav) for this case. The problem is that you have an `<a>` in `<a>` and when you click it then it get's confused.

So I've changed the `<a ng-show="collapsed">` to `<div ng-show="collapsed">` and now works as expected (see pen too).

Comment: Yes I tried it , but still not working , I tried also to put just <a href=.. ></a> but it does not work, it seems that everything in this collapse doesn't work

Comment: Yes it works, I can see more information when I click

Comment: Yes you're right, I change it, and I had to change /modifClient to modifClient, but what if I want this "modifClient/{{x.CodeClient}} ? please

Comment: try `<a class="button button-info" ng-href="modifClient/{{x.CodeClient}}"> ...` and I think I answerd your orig question.

Comment: It doesn't work with ng-href, it s ui-sref and without / , Mr.chsdk gived me the right answer but you you gived the trick of "div",I do not know to whom I have to give the answer

Comment: that's strange, because on the pen it works with the `ng-href`, `\\ ` and the `div`, but I guess you have more under the hood that you've shared going on

Comment: When I put ng-href it gives me this error: Cannot GET /modifClient

Comment: try to put `#/modifClient` or try so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14202514/1595977 but also the `ui-sref` is a valid answer.

Comment: Thank you Edwin! ng-href and div are the trick to solve my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Angular **ui-router**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference) and `modifClient` is a state in your router, you better use the Angular `ui-sref` attribute instead of HTML `href`.

Your code would be :

```
<a class="button button-info" ui-sref="modifClient">
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to pass an object param in the `ui-sref` you can do it like this:

```
<a class="button button-info" ui-sref="modifClient({CodeClient: x.CodeClient})">
```

And change your `state` settings to include a `params` object:

```
$stateProvider.state('modifClient', {
     url: '/modifClient',
     templateUrl: 'templates/modifClient.html',
     params: {CodeClient: null},
     controller: 'ConsultClientCtrl' 
});
```

**Note:**

Note that you should also update your `ConsultClientCtrl` controller with a `$scope.CodeClient` variable so it can be updated from the `ui-sref`.

You can read **[How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller)** for further options.

---

**Edit 2:**

After reading your last Edit, I can see that you don't have a `CodeClient` variable in your controller, so update it like this:

```
app.controller("ConsultClientCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.CodeClient = null;
    $scope.loadClient = function(){ 
       $http.get("http://localhost/deb/debut.php")  
       .success(function(data){  
            $scope.names = data; 
       });  
   }
});
```

And in your HTML just use:

```
<div class="item item-divider center-text"> {{CodeClient}} </div>
```

Without `<ion-list ng-repeat ...>` and the `filter` part as we already got the `CodeClient` variable in the Controller.

Comment: @SalamSalam Try it without the `/`, I mean `ui-sref="modifClient"`, because we shoul refer to the state name and not it's url.

Comment: It works when I changed the <a> to <div> and with doing what you suggested, but the problem now I have informations of all clients, what If want to use this please: ui-sref="modifClient/{{CodeClient}}"

Comment: @SalamSalam you should pass them like this: `ui-sref="modifClient({client: x})"`.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, I still have the informations of all clients!

Comment: @SalamSalam If you want to pass only the `CodeClient` value, you should use `x.CodeClient` in `ui-sref="modifClient({CodeClient: x.CodeClient})"` as `x`  will hold all the client details. I updated my answer, check it.

Comment: I tried this, and still have the same problem, even the url doesn't change when I click:: still: ...../#/modifClient

Comment: Thank you, Im really sorry, but still have all information

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for every one,This is the solution I found:

change the code of the button:

```
<a class="button button-info" ng-href="#/modifClient/{{x.CodeClient}}" >
Enregistrer </a>
```

And in app.js, I had to use $state:

```
app.controller("ConsultClientCtrl", function($scope, $http,$state) {

        $scope.loadClient = function(){ 
              $http.get("http://localhost/deb/selectClient.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.thisX   = $state.params.CodeClient; 
                $scope.names = data;  
           });
         }             
});
```

And changing the state provider to this:

```
$stateProvider.state('modifClient', {
            url: '/modifClient/:CodeClient',
            templateUrl: 'templates/modifClient.html',
            controller: 'ConsultClientCtrl' 
        });
```