# Can I call Route Provider service in Controller in angular js asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using controller in my Angularjs which gets question one by one from server and i want on specific condition this controller should call a routeprovider that should change my current view with templateUrl and put into a directive

my question is can i call route provider in controller rather than module

here is my CreateController

```
var CreateController = ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.model = {

    };
................>

.................>
    $scope.NextQuestion = function () {

        $http.post('/Testing/NextQuestion', {

            ........................>

        }).success(function (newdata) {
            $scope.model = newdata;
            var inccomplevel = $scope.model.servercomplevel;
            if (qId == 10) {
                  here i need the code for routeProvider and directive please provide me help
            }
......................>
    }];
```

i did the route provider in app.js file there it works

here is the code for app.js when i do like this it works and when i shift the code of route provider

to the create controller in condition if qId == 10 there it does not work

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('CreateController', CreateController);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
            templateUrl: 'Partials/TestCompleted.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
    app.controller("AppCtrl",function ($scope) {
        $scope.newmodel = {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I think is not clear your issue or question, please re-raise

Comment: Instead of editing a question to ask another completely unrelated question, simply ask another question. I would suggest reverting your edits. No one see this question and won't be of any help to you.

Comment: It's entirely unfair to @DouglasLudlow and the time he spent working on your question to change it like you did here. Please do not do that again.

Comment: I did not get the answer thats why I changed

Comment: and I can't ask any more question in stack over flow that's why i edit the Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the value of the templateUrl on the route, you should define another route. Then you can simply switch routes.

To change the route/view, you need update the path. You can do this using the [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

See [AngularJS : How do I switch views from a controller function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003916/how-do-i-switch-views-in-angularjs-from-a-controller-function)