# AngularJS: Passing variables between controllers

Tags: angularjs, service, controllers

I am new to angular and I'm trying to find a method of passing variables between controllers. I saw the best method of achieving this was by using a service, as shown here - 
[AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers)

However, this doesn't seem to be working with my code, as I will explain at the bottom.

Here is my service code,

```
app.service('loginService', function ($http) {

var loggedInUser = []

//If the login was successful this will be used
this.setLoginDetails = function(userDetails){
    loggedInUser.push(userDetails);
}

this.GetLoginUsername = function () {
    return loggedInUser.Username;
}

});
```

And now my two controllers,

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, loginService, $location, $window) {

$scope.authenticateLogin = function () {

    // get record
    var user = {
        Username: $scope.username,
        Password: $scope.password
    };


    var promisePost = loginService.post(user);
    promisePost.then(function (result) {
        var res = result.data;
        //This is the important line
        loginService.setLoginDetails(user);

        $window.location.href = loginPageUrl;
    },
        function (errorResult) {
            console.log("Unable to log in : " + errorResult);
        });
}
});
```

my Controller that is trying to retrieve the information that has been set,

```
app.controller('userController', function ($scope, userService, $window, $modal, loginService) {

// Get the current logged in user
$scope.LoggedInAs = loginService.GetLoginUsername();

});
```

The issue I am having is that the username is being correctly set with the first controller, but when I try to access that information with the second controller the value for loggedInUser in null so the value is not being saved between the controllers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's due to: `$window.location.href = loginPageUrl;` which refreshes the page rather than changing the state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What should I be using instead of this?

Comment: Try something like this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: The other option is to store the login credentials (Which you'll probably want to do anyway) in a cookie or session to be read at a later date.

Comment: I think $location.path should do it for u.
This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003916/how-do-i-switch-views-in-angularjs-from-a-controller-function

Comment: yeah location.path() worked when I adapted my solution to start using ngroute properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var loggedInUser = []` is an array, so if you want to get username you will have to do `loggedInUser[0].Username` and not `loggedInUser.Username`.

```
this.GetLoginUsername = function () {
    return loggedInUser[0].Username;
}
```

Also, as stated in comments either use ngRoute/uiRouter to change the page/url...

Comment: Did some more digging into ngroute, which I hadn't used before, and managed to get it working like that.